# Restore files that are not in the Bacula database using a Bacula file deamon

Tags: backup, backup-restoration, bacula

I have a backup made with Bacula on tapes. Files are not listed in the Bacula's catalog.

I want to restore files inside the directory, listed one per line in `needed.lst` (last line empty) onto a remote host `remote_host` using the file daemon which has been installed on it.  In my case, no network file-system has been installed on my director's host.

For the restore onto my director's host, I would simply use something like

```
bextract -V* -i needed.lst -p Ultrium-1 -v -p /some/retore/dir
```

How can I get my file to be written on `remote_host` instead of the host where  `bextract` is executed?  I have no need to places those files in the Bacula database which is already a bit huge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *bextract* manual (at least for ver. 5.2, the most popular in distros) does not list any option to specify remote host. So your options are:

1. mount a share from the remote machine in the director's OS;
2. create a temporary, empty catalog database and use *bscan* to recover all metadata and proceed with normal recovery.

From Bacula manual:

*The bscan program can be used to re-create a database (catalog) records from the backup information written to one or more Volumes. This is normally needed only if one or more Volumes have been pruned or purged from your catalog so that the records on the Volume are no longer in the catalog, or for Volumes that you have archived.*

In any case, it can be helpful if you have bootstrap files created during the backup process, so you won't have to create it by hand.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a normal restore as long as the Bacula catalog (database) has information about the backup job and the media volumes it uses.

When file information has been pruned, the restore operation in bconsole will prompt you if you want to restore all files, and if you decline, it will prompt you for a regular expression to restore a subset of files.  The latter functionality was added in Bacula 3.0.